# Bash syntax error egrep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Hello I am working on a small bash script to analyse virus logs from ClamAV, and it seems to not like my usage of `|` in my egrep regular expression:

Output:

```
Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

Line 52 which it says is wrong:

```
INFECT_FILE_NAME="$(${CAT} ${DIR}${FILE} | ${EGREP} -oE \"[\/|\][a-z|A-Z| |0-9|\.|_|-|+]{1,9001}:\" | ${SED} -e 's/[:|\/|\|\\|\/\/]//g')"; \
```

The issue here seems to be with the egrep part, I tried replacing "|" with "." and even escaping them like so: "\|", however I have no luck so far.

Running the commands in CLI mode and using the regular expressions as they are here works just fine and as I expect them to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There seems to be a stray `\\` after the variable.

Comment: That is not a stray, I use these to indicate that end of file/if statement is not reached yet. I guess it is a bad practise, however they are throughout this script and seems not to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: The error looks like it is with `|`, but it's actually not. It's a result of an unescaped ` \ ` or ` / ` in the `EGREP` or `SED` commands most likely.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense... Having issues pin-pointing where that one unescaped character is though.

Comment: What's `{1,9001}` for? If you wanted an arbitrarily high number of repeats you could just use `+`. (9001 seems arbitrary)

Comment: Internal joke mostly, 1,9001 (over nine thousand) meaning anything from 1-9001 I won't have that as it is very unlikely that it will be 9001 characters. I want to look into your `+` suggestion though.

Comment: Code is no place to put jokes.  Anything that makes the following programmer ask "What's that for?" unnecessarily should be avoided.

Comment: Why do you have `CAT` and `EGREP` and `SED` as variables? This is generally very poor practice. Simply use the command names, and let the user manage their `PATH` if there are any issues.

Comment: What is this piece of code supposed to accomplish? If at all possible, you should get the infected file's name in a machine-readable format from the scanner in the first place. Your code looks incredibly brittle, and I think I see at least two errors as well as multiple stylistic issues, but without sample input and output, it's awfully hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly not escaped a space character and a slash character. Fixed now.